# troubleshooting python code

Tags: python, ssl, network-programming

I am in  my first steps in learning python so excuse my questions please. I want to run the code below (taken from: http://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html) :

```
import socket, ssl, pprint
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# require a certificate from the server
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,
                           ca_certs="F:/cert",
                           cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)

ssl_sock.connect(('www.versign.com', 443))

print repr(ssl_sock.getpeername())
print ssl_sock.cipher()
print pprint.pformat(ssl_sock.getpeercert())

# Set a simple HTTP request -- use httplib in actual code.
ssl_sock.write("""GET / HTTP/1.0\r
Host: www.verisign.com\r\n\r\n""")

# Read a chunk of data.  Will not necessarily
# read all the data returned by the server.
data = ssl_sock.read()

# note that closing the SSLSocket will also close the underlying socket
ssl_sock.close()
```

I got the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\e\workspace\PythonTesting\source\HelloWorld.py", line 38, in 
>       ssl_sock.connect(('www.versign.com', 443))
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 331, in connect
>
> ```
> self._real_connect(addr, False)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 314, in _real_connect
>
> self.ca_certs, self.ciphers)
>
> ssl.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:340: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib

The error reporting in python does not look guiding to find the source of the problem. i might be mistaken. Can anybody help in telling me what is the problem in the code ?

Comment: I also have this type of problem then installed pip install requests[security]  , update ssl and certifi

Answer (score 3):

This is one area where the Python standard library is known to be difficult to use. Instead you may want to use the requests library. Documentation on sending certificates is available at: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Answer (score 2):

Your code is referring to a certificate *file* on drive 'F:' (using the `ca_certs` parameter), which is not found during execution -- is there one?

See the relevant [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket):

> The ca_certs file contains a set of concatenated “certification
>   authority” certificates, which are used to validate certificates
>   passed from the other end of the connection.

Comment: Yes. There is a folder in F: drive with the same name.

Comment: it's something to do with the path -- check if there are write permissions, also try "F:\\cert\\ca_cart.txt". It should be pointing to a file, not just folder.

Answer (score 0):

Does the certificate referenced exist on your filesystem? I think that error is in response to invalid cert from this code:

ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,ca_certs="F:/cert",cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)

Comment: Do you mean that the certificate must be in `F:/cert` folder ? It is not. As far as I understand from the source website that the code function is to extract the SSL server certificate: `This example connects to an SSL server, prints the server’s address and certificate, sends some bytes, and reads part of the response`

Comment: Yea you need the certificate. From the documentation: "The keyfile and certfile parameters specify optional files which contain a certificate to be used to identify the local side of the connection. See the discussion of Certificates for more information on how the certificate is stored in the certfile."